# Losing Reference of currently opened View

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, self, iboutlet

When Push Notifications has been received in app delegate did receive, what i am doing is taking the last object from navigation stack and calling one of the function of that class.

```
    if([[self.navigationController.viewControllers lastObject] isKindOfClass:[JFFriendsListViewController class]]){
                JFFriendsListViewController *friendlist=[self.navigationController.viewControllers lastObject];

                [friendlist RefreshRequiredOnSameView];
            }
```

Please help How to get the scrollview from xib??

And When i touch any view... It again regain the Iboutlets references from xib.

Comment: Did you properly connect IBOutlet with scroll view ?

Comment: Yes. IBoutlets are connected properly, Every thing is working, only case when it is not working is when i receive push and based on push i have to make changes on uiview.

Comment: Are you sure your view is allocated at the time when you are using it?

Comment: I fetch the uiviewcontroller from navigation as mentioned above.... and call the corresponding function to make change in the uiview. But Views are not responding.

Comment: So steps is ReceiveNotification > called RefreshRequiredOnSameview > task perform somthing in RefreshRequiredOnSameView > You get friendScrollview == nil(BUG) !! right ?

Comment: You mean function RefereshRequiredOnSameView is not called ?

Comment: Yes Jageen... You are right. This is the exact scenario... Kindly suggest. I am trying it since last two days. I need to implement the autorefresh functionality as soon as possible..

Comment: Jageen, Function is called.. views are returning nil

Comment: can you try [self.view layoutIfNeeded]  inside your RefereshRequiredOnSameView method

Comment: @Sanjay if you think that code written in RefereshRequiredOnSameView could be the reason please paste that code also

Comment: is your navigationController Rootviewcontroller of UIWindow????

Comment: @Deepak!!! I am trying your suggestion. Get back to you soon. @Jageen Please look into the edited code....!!!

Answer (score 1):

Run your app and go to the `JFFriendsListViewController` page and add a debugger inside `viewDidLoad` and check the memory address of this class.

Again when you receive push notes then here

`JFFriendsListViewController *friendlist=[self.navigationController.viewControllers lastObject];`
again check the memory address of `friendlist`. 
Are they same???
I think wen you are receiving push notes you are using diff `JFFriendsListViewController` instance and your subviews are not loading in main thread yet.